# Ensure that a 'Parent's onclick event will be fired when a child anchor is clicked?

Tags: javascript

My issue is just the opposite from the previous posting labled:
**How do I prevent a parent's onclick event from firing when a child anchor is clicked?**

I have a 'Parent' page which will dynamically load a DIV's innerHTML with an 'external'  HTML document.   That works fine.

I also have a Search function which looks into the text of all of the 'external' HTML documents to see if it finds one (or more) which contain the SearchText.
If it finds one (or more) it then creates a new HTML page:  SearchResults.htm.
Within that SearchResults.htm it lists the 'found' documents as links - each with its own onclick() method and then displays that new SearchResults HTML document in the same DIV's innerHTML.
The display itself works fine.

'Child' Page Link Example:

```html
<a href = "#" onclick = "DisplayDocument('1-Disposition-4-Generate
Single Letter.htm')" href = "#">Disposition-Generate Single Letter</a>
```

However the js function DisplayDocument()  is resident in the 'Parent' page.

My problem is that when I click on the 'Child' page link it seems as though it begins looking for the js function within the 'Child' page where there are NO js functions at all and it never seems to attempt to find it in the 'Parent' page.

How can I:
1) Prevent the onclick from looking within the 'Child' page?
2) Ensure that a 'Parent's onclick event will be fired when a child anchor is clicked?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well once again it looks like I will have to answer my own question.

When I was

> dynamically loading a DIV's innerHTML with an 'external' HTML document.

I was putting the SearchResults HTML document code into an HTML Object and then putting the Object into the innerHTML.

That worked just fine when I was loading the 'external' HTML documents, but it was not working for the SearchResults document which had links in it - each with their own onClick().

Well I found out that instead of creating a SearchResults document, I just needed to load the 'raw' HTML code (representing the SearchResults) into the innerHTML without it being within an HTML Object,

Then I was able to successfully execute the js code on the SearchResults links.

Hopefully this might help someone else facing the same problem.